# Keyboard not showing on simple Customized WebView (without code change), Why?

Tags: android, webview, android-custom-view

I have a simple WebView as below

```
<WebView
    android:id="@+id/my_web_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

the above works well, and when I click on the Edit Text (Input Element on the webview), the keyboard appears.

I'm thinking of customizing my WebView. So I wrote a class, inherit from WebView as below (empty body for now, so everything is as per WebView).

```
class MyWebView @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null, defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) : WebView(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) { }
```

So to use my custom WebView, my view changed to

```
<my.package.MyWebView
    android:id="@+id/my_web_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

All compile fine, and the webview got loaded. However, when the Edit Text (Input Element on the webview) got click, the Keyboard no longer visible.

What happen? How could I still have the same keyboard behavior visible with my Custom WebView?

Comment: Try use Webview. Not use Custom Webview. and talk to me result?

Comment: As mentioned in my question, webview works fine. Only custom webview not showing.

Comment: Try add webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); in Your Java Code

Comment: Unrelated to JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

I got the workaround of showing the keyboard

```
<my.package.MyWebView
    android:id="@+id/my_web_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true" />
```

But I still don't understand why on normal WebView, the `android:focusable="true"` and `android:focusableInTouchMode="true"` is not needed. Hopes someone to explain.